# Code Not fulfilling all the Sample Inputs' result on HackerRank

Tags: python, string, loops

Question on HackerRank-   You are asked to ensure that the first and last names of people begin with a capital letter in their passports. For example, alison heck should be capitalised correctly as Alison Heck.(What they actually want is to capitalize the first letter of every individual string)

```
 def solve(s):
        0<len(s)<1000
        abc=[]
        for p in s.split():
            abc.append(p.capitalize())
            x=" ".join(abc)
        return x
```

I am getting correct answers on putting my own custom inputs but HackerRank says otherwise.(4/6 Sample Inputs are unsatisfied)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arr = ['muhammad Atif', 'alison heck','dr dexter Morgan']
def capitalizeName(word):
    words = word.split(' ')
    for i in range(0,len(words)):
        words[i] = words[i].capitalize()
    
    return ' '.join(words)
    
for word in arr:
    print(capitalizeName(word))
```

Hopefully, This simple function will solve your problem. Further, modify it according to the hackerrank criteria . i-e print or return statements etc